# How to calculate mean of each slice in tensorflow tensor?

Tags: python, tensorflow, neural-network

I have a stack of images, a tensor shape=(?, 64, 64). I am trying to apply a mask to each image, get the mean value of pixels within the mask, and compare to mean value calculated using a different mask. I would use this for comparing mean squared error. Normally, I would calculate this by looping through slices but tensorflow doesn't allow looping. Any suggestions how to do this?

```
for l in range(NumberOfExams): 
I = images[l,:,:]
    meansRef[l] = I[referenceMasks[l,:,:]]
    meansOut[l] = I[calculatedMasks[l,:,:]]

MSE = np.mean((meansRef - meansOut)**2/meansRef**2)
```

I have tried using tf.boolean_mask which can give me mean value based on all referenceMasks and for calculatedMasks but so far it's not clear to me how to get a per image mean value using this or another tensorflow method.

Many thanks.

Comment: Can't you use convolution for this? I.e. use the mask as a "filter" and convolve it over the image.

Comment: Convolution makes a lot of sense. Trying to figure out how to frame it - both images and calculated masks are [batch_size,height,width,1]. Filter in e.g. tf.nn.conv2d should be [height,width,channel_in,channel_out]. I've tried to reshape calculatedMasks to be [height,width,batch_size,batch_size] aiming to get a [1,1,batch_size] output but it doesn't seem to be working. One other issue is that batch_size is technically None, so I'm not sure I can reshape it using "-1":  tf.nn.conv2d(images,tf.reshape(calculatedMasks,[xsze,ysze,-1,-1]),stride=1,padding='VALID')

Comment: I've figured out the dimension = None issue - can use tf.shape(images)[0]. Since the entire batch of masks needs to be used, my current best guess is to pretend images in a batch are channels: imgReshape = tf.reshape(images,[1,xsze*ysze,-1])
    kernel = tf.reshape(masks,[xsze*ysze,tf.shape(images)[0],1])
    y_slice_means = tf.nn.conv1d(img,kernel,stride=1,padding='VALID'). This gives the reasonable output dimensions of (1,1,batch_size) but the mean values are wrong. I am not quite sure how channels_in/channels_out are used by the conv function - I suspect that's the issue

Comment: If your images are [batch, h, w, 1] a filter of shape [h, w, 1, 1] with padding=valid should give you a [batch, 1, 1, 1] result.

Comment: @Alexandre Passos Right but the suggestion was to use the batch of masks as the "filter". i.e. the filter shape would not be [h, w, 1, 1] but something like [h, w, batch, 1]. However, convolving with that gives values which are all equal, rather than differences mean(Image[ReferenceMask]) - mean(Image[calculatedMask]) as desired.

Comment: Yes that will not work, I recommend you do num_batch independent h,w,1,1 convolutions and stack the result.

Comment: @Alexandre Passos Thanks but how to do this without loops, since tensorflow doesn't allow them? I am having trouble getting means only within a mask for each image (as in the original post). tf.boolean_mask concatenates points across all images in batch.

Comment: You can use tf.map_fn to do this loop I believe.

Comment: @Alexandre Passos. Yes! I did recently find that, just didn't have a chance to post the answer. It seems to work!

Answer (score 0):

The comparison of masked means for each image can be achieved using the `tf.map_fn`. This returns the result of an arbitrary operation on each image in a batch, essentially allowing looping:

So:

```
for l in range(NumberOfExams): 
I = images[l,:,:]
    meansRef[l] = I[referenceMasks[l,:,:]]
    meansOut[l] = I[calculatedMasks[l,:,:]]

MSE = np.mean((meansRef - meansOut)**2)
```

Can be done as (can maybe use cleanup):

```
calculatedMasksInf = tf.where(calc_mask > 0.5,Ex,-np.inf * tf.ones_like(calc_mask ))
referenceMasksInf = tf.where(ref_mask > 0.5, Ex, -np.inf * tf.ones_like(ref_mask ))

stiff_means_calculated = tf.map_fn(lambda frame: tf.reduce_mean(tf.boolean_mask(frame,tf.logical_not(tf.is_inf(frame)))), calculatedMasksInf)
stiff_means_reference = tf.map_fn(lambda frame: tf.reduce_mean(tf.boolean_mask(frame,tf.logical_not(tf.is_inf(frame)))), referenceMasksInf)

SqErr = (stiff_means_calculated - stiff_means_reference) ** 2
MSE = tf.reduce_mean(tf.boolean_mask(SqErr,tf.logical_not(tf.is_nan(SqErr))))
```